# How to make parallel API calls in Remix.run

Tags: reactjs, typescript, strapi, tsx, remix.run

I have a Remix.run with (TSX) application which has multiple Components with multiple API calls That they need to make to a strapi API how can I Call all the API's in parallel such that either the website renders the images/text from API in build time or calls them asynchronously on client's browser?

I am new to this please help, Any resources to refer or some snippets might help.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Check out the strapi example. If it doesn't answer your question, modify it and include the updated example. https://github.com/remix-run/examples/tree/main/strapi

Comment: I feel like the remix approach would be to fetch data from the strapi api in your loader function, and then access your strapi data with useLoaderData on the client side code. That would do the page building on the server side. If you need a client side approach, you could use multiple useFetchers' for all of strapi routes.